# Xamarin bindings java library - No package found

Tags: java, android, binding, jar, xamarin

Im want to link an android jar library to my Xamarin project, i do everything covered by the online doc on Xamarin website.

But when i compile the binding project i got a warning that say : **No Package Found**.

If i replace the desired Jar by another, let say picasso.jar for example, i don't have this error and the binding projet compile without problems.

I can't link the jar library because of an NDA engagement.

But it's possible that the problems is that i get the .jar from a repository supposed to be build by maven/gradle and not a final .jar compiled?

What can i do to track the real error behind this "no package found"

A DLL is correctly generated at the end of the process, but added it to the main project don't give me any classes from the original jar.

Answer (score 1):

As I thought this is the fault to the jar from maven repository. Inside the jar we got java files and not compiled files.

So i take an compiled jar (aar files) and everything work now.